# Mark lines between two records in Power BI table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

How can I add a new column in DAX in Power BI in a table and mark with an X the records that are between the last status of “IN PRODUCTION” of an order and the first status of “IN PRODUCTION” of the next order?

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
NEW COLUMN = 
VAR CurrentOrder = [ORDER]
VAR NextOrder = 
    CALCULATE(
        FIRSTNONBLANK('Table'[ORDER], 1),
        FILTER(
            ALL('Table'),
            'Table'[ORDER] > CurrentOrder
        )
    )
RETURN
    IF(
        [STATUS] <> "IN PRODUCTION" && 
        (NextOrder = BLANK() || NOT(ISBLANK(NextOrder))),
        "X",
        BLANK()
    )
```